# Xamarin local notification dosen't work

Tags: xamarin, android-notifications

I'm trying implement local notification in my app, but in one case I can't build app a second case I have error.

My code.
Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GNote
{
    public interface INotification
    {
        void LocalNotification();
    }
}
```

Dependecy service:

```
DependencyService.Get<INotification>().LocalNotification();
```

Class NotificationService:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;

namespace GNote.Droid
{
    class NotificationService : INotification
    {
        public void LocalNotification()
        {
            // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle("Sample Notification")
                .SetContentText("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_audiotrack_dark);

            // Build the notification:
            Notification notification = builder.Build();

            // Get the notification manager:
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
            Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Publish the notification:
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);

        }
    }
}
```

I followed xamarin documentation guide [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/)
and in constructor used **this**
*Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)*

But in this case I have error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GNote.Droid.NotificationService' to
>   'Android.Content.Context'

I found other example of implementation [example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25016/xamarin-forms-and-local-notification) 
and instead of **this** use **Application.Context**.
But then I have

> An unhandled exception occured. occurred

when try create notification.

Can you tell me how fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to change the context parameter value in

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
```

to

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
```